# How do I set failover on my netapp clusters?

Tags: netapp

I have two clusters of NetApp (main and dr), in each I have two nodes.

If one of the nodes in either cluster goes down, the other node kicks in and act as one node cluster.
Now my question is, what happens when a whole cluster falls down due to problems of power supply?

I've heard about "Metro Cluster" but I want to ask if there is another option to do so.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what RPO you need. Metrocluster does synchronous replication of every write and thus provides zero RPO (data loss)

On the other hand you could use Snapmirror which basically takes periodic snapshots and stores them on the other cluster. As you can imagine you should expect some data loss.